# Evaluate a value after a watcher is run Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have watcher code which gets triggered whenever an item is changed from a dropdown. I am trying to get the value of `$scope.from_date` **after** the event occurs but the value being returned from the console log is the value before the event is triggered.

```
        $scope.$watch('strSelectedDateRange', function(strNewRange, strOldRange) {
        if (strNewRange && strNewRange !== strOldRange) {

            if ($scope.strSelectedDateRange === 'custom') {
                $scope.bShowDateRange = true;
                checkHourlyCustomDateRange();
                $scope.setCustomDateRange();
            } else {
                $scope.bShowDateRange = false; // for safety
                $scope.strCurDateRange = $scope.strSelectedDateRange;
                $this.getReportData($scope.deal);
            }
        }


        console.log($scope.from_date)

    });
```

Comment: Please, create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can reproduce the problem. With this information is hard to tell what the problem is.

Comment: you have just _subscribed_ callback for some _future_ changes and immediately after that you are making that `console.log` call. Data has not been changed yet, so old value is shown in console.

Comment: in other words statement in title contradicts with code itself: value is actually evaluated not after a watcher _runs_ rather after watcher _has been created_

Answer (score 0):

This the the link to example code:
[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/SQuVy/2827/)

```
angular.module('watchApp', []).controller('watchCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.watchVariable = "hghj";

    $scope.$watch('watchVariable', function(newVal, oldVal) {
        // do something here
        $scope.oldVal = oldVal;
        $scope.newVal = newVal;
    }, true);
});
```